# WCF REST - Configuration-based, Extensionless (.svc-less) Route Without Global.asax?

Tags: wcf, rest, asp.net-routing

In a WCF REST service, hosted in IIS 7.5, .NET 4.03 or maybe 4.5... 
is it possible to configure a .svc-less (file-less, extensionless) ServiceRoute **in the web.config alone**, without creating a Global.asax for RouteTable.Routes.Add, without IIS tricks, without HTTP modules, and not a RoutingService?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The alternatives for svc-less, webhosted WCF services are the ones you listed. The most common ones are using the routing (RouteTable.Routes.Add) or IIS address rewriting (via a module). You could in theory write a "pure" ASP.NET project which forwards the requests to the .svc endpoint, but that is just a routing service in disguise.